# How to compile Coq files with Proof General + Emacs?

Tags: coq

Now that I am moving on from Software Foundations where everything is served on a platter I am having trouble figuring out how to set up my own projects. There are [some instructions](https://izgzhen.github.io/2016/09/19/coq-dev.html) out there, but since I am just starting out I find this too complex when trying to set up a hello world program. Also I have some other issues.

```
hello.v
```

The way I've managed to compile an empty `hello.v` is by putting the above in the `_CoqProject` file and then running...

```
coq_makefile -o Makefile.coq -f _CoqProject
```

This makes the makefiles.

```
make -f Makefile.coq
```

This compiles the project, but I can't get `make hello` to work with just this and Proof General happens to use this when compiling individual files.

```
make hello.vo
make: *** No rule to make target 'hello.vo'.  Stop.
```

The above is what I get when I try compiling from Proof General.

What should I do here? What would be the simplest possible way to set up a project with an empty file for use with Proof General + Emacs?

```
-Q . VFA
```

Also, why does SF vol 3 work despite not having much in its `_CoqProject` file? It only has the above.

Comment: What do you mean by "compiling from Proof General"?  Proof General is an emacs editing mode. You don't call make from Proof General... or?

Comment: There is a `Coq -> COQ PROG (ARGS) -> Compile` button in Emacs when using PG with Coq files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 2022 Update

There is a template to create new projects and to generate the associated boilerplate: https://github.com/coq-community/templates

---

### Original answer

Here's what a conventional setup looks like (it's not actually standardized, you will find variations in the wild, especially for old projects, and future projects with `dune` now supporting Coq):

```
_CoqProject
Makefile
theories/
  hello.v
```

With the following `_CoqProject`:

```
-Q theories/ MyProject
theories/hello.v
# list paths to .v files here
```

In particular, qualifying the project (`-Q path/ ProjectName`) avoids ambiguities (if the same module name is used elsewhere) and makes it easier to import from other projects later.

And the following `Makefile`:

```
build: Makefile.coq
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.coq

Makefile.coq: _CoqProject
    coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o Makefile.coq

.PHONY: build
```

The `build` target is marked `.PHONY` to indicate that it's not meant to create a file/directory. This avoids problems when other tools create a `build` directory for whatever reason.

### Command line

To build the whole project from the command line, type `make` (which is equivalent to `make build` by default because `build` is the first command of the `Makefile`).
To build only one `.vo` file, for example `theories/hello.vo`, type `make -f Makefile.coq theories/hello.vo`. It must be listed in the `_CoqProject` (so that `coq_makefile` then puts it into `Makefile.coq.conf`).

### Proof General

In Proof General there is an option "Compile Before Require", which does as its name says. (Coq > Auto Compilation > Compile Before Require)

The `coq-Compile` command you seem to have been using appears abandoned given its current lack of configurability. `coq-Compile` calls `make hello.vo`, but there is no `hello.vo` target in  the `Makefile`, which is the one `make` looks at by default, unless the `-f` option is set. One way to make this PG command work with that setup is to include the generated `Makefile.coq` inside the `Makefile`:

```
# Add this line to Makefile to enable PG's "coq-Compile"
-include Makefile.coq
```

I'm personally hesitant to do that because I don't really understand what's in `Makefile.coq`.

---

> Also, why does SF vol 3 work despite not having much in its _CoqProject file? It only has the above.

All SF volumes work that way now. For interactive editing with Proof General/CoqIDE, only the `-Q` option matters (actually, `-R` and a few others too), not the filenames. The filenames are used by `coq_makefile`, but you could also change the invocation of `coq_makefile` to get the filenames from elsewhere, for example as direct command line arguments:

```
# If _CoqProject only contains the -Q option
coq_makefile -f _CoqProject theories/hello.v
```

Comment: From my experimentation, I am not convinced that `-include Makefile.coq` is enough to enable PG functionality. Or that the VFA `Makefile` was generated by `coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o Makefile`. If you look at the VFA `Makefile`, you will see that that it explicitly has the included files like `Perm.v`. Comparing it with the generated file from the directory's `_CoqProject`, it is obvious that they are different. Are there some compilation options we are missing here? I suppose they could have always put in the files by hand, but I find that unlikely.

Comment: The `Makefile` in Software Foundations isn't really representative of how Coq projects are packaged, but you can see the full command used in the `Makefile.conf` target of `Makefile` (if I run `coq_makefile` with Coq 8.8 I get mostly the same file except for minor environmental differences). The extra options are mostly irrelevant, but you can see that the Coq files are listed directly on the command line. They are just listed elsewhere in Software Foundation's config before getting here. As far as I can tell, `-include Makefile.coq` is enough as long as `Makefile.coq` has been generated.

Comment: I am having too many problems to deal with in the comments, so how about we move this [to here](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/10676)?